# android setError() issue - not working as expected

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm using `edittext.setError(char...)` method for showing error for edit-text if it's blank.
But now facing two issue, which I unable to resolve.

1) When showing error "Field can't be blank" with red icon and popup. But when opening keyboard by clicking on any other edit-text, error popup don't move with edit-text field and both icon and error message shows on two different places.

2) My `EditText` field have show and hide button at right corner. Once I set `setError(char...)`, then toggle between show/hide not happening. Below is code snippet for toggle show/hide.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && mDrawableRight!=null){
          mRectBounds = mDrawableRight.getBounds();
          final int x = (int)event.getX();
          final int y = (int)event.getY();
          if(x>=(this.getRight()-mRectBounds.width()) && x<=(this.getRight()-this.getPaddingRight())&& y>=this.getPaddingTop() && y<=(this.getHeight()-this.getPaddingBottom())){
            if(this.getInputType() == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD){
                this.setTransformationMethod(null);
                this.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
                this.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.show), null);
              } else {
              this.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
              this.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
              this.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hide), null);
            } 
            event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
          }
        } 
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

Comment: I do not like the name of your method that shows/hide the password. checkForValidMethod

Comment: Also why are using this complex on touch event handler instead of using onclick?

Comment: How can we use 'onclick()' for show/hide icon in right corner of EditText? 
The above code snippet is to find out click on show/hide icon of EditText at right corner.

Comment: Add click listener for that icon on the right side of the edittext.

Comment: hmm..and can we get click for icon at right side in EditText? Have you any example?